# How to take in multiple inputs from user in assembly

Tags: assembly, input, 64-bit, nasm

I'm pretty new to assembly. I know how to take in 1 value from a user, but what if I want the user to input 3 numbers separated by spaces.

I'm trying to store each of them into a separate register, so something like this.

```
push qword 0                        ;make space for 8-byte number
push qword 0                        ;make space for 8-byte number
push qword 0                        ;make space for 8-byte number                                            
mov qword  rdi, formatfloatinput                            
mov qword  rsi, rsp                                         
mov qword  rax, 0                                           
call       scanf                                            


pop qword r15                   ;pop value from stack into r15                            
pop qword r14                   ;pop next value in stack into r14?
pop qword r13                   ;pop next value in stack into r13?
```

sample input: `13 15 36`

Now `r15` should contain 13, `r14` contains 15 and `r13` contains 36.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C equivalent would be `scanf("%ld %ld %ld", &r15, &r14, &r13)`. Notice that you have to pass 3 pointers, to each of your output variables. You only pass 1. Also, your `formatfloatinput` is misleading, you are reading into integer registers, you need an integer format. Something like this should work:

```
push qword 0                        ;make space for 8-byte number
push qword 0                        ;make space for 8-byte number
push qword 0                        ;make space for 8-byte number
mov qword  rdi, format
mov qword  rsi, rsp                 ; &r15
lea rdx, [rsp+8]                    ; &r14
lea rcx, [rsp+16]                   ; &r13
mov qword  rax, 0
call       scanf
pop qword r15                   ;pop value from stack into r15
pop qword r14                   ;pop next value in stack into r14?
pop qword r13                   ;pop next value in stack into r13?
....
format: db "%ld %ld %ld", 0
```

Pushing and popping like you do is not the usual way to write this, but isn't wrong as such. Remember to keep the stack aligned if the calling convention requires that.